# Pycharm integration with Anaconda 3.6.0

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I'm having a little bit of trouble with Pycharm Community recognizing Anaconda 3.6.0. The interpreter works and runs programs, however, it doesn't seem to be reading the code intuitively and providing any of the suggestive features (autocompletion) or colouring for the different text (i.e all text is just grey). So it's more like a featureless text editor that can run code then a sophisticated IDE at the moment.

When using standard Python 2.7 as the interpreter it has all of the normal features that should be appearing. I thought Pycharm had full support for Anaconda and should have these features. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what to do? Thanks!

Comment: have you checked the configuration settings of the project to make sure it's detecting python interpreter ? Take a look here for help https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are making sure to select the right interpreter for both the project as well as general interpreter in File->settings. I have installed anaconda for both  python 2.7 and python 3. I specify the path of the anaconda version I want to use  for the current project and it works fine.